# PowerShell - Using -Recurse and -Filter to append to all files in a directory

Tags: powershell, filter, get-childitem

I'm trying to find all `.aspx` files in a directory and all of its child folders so that I can add a tag under the `<head>` tag. Parent directories may contain `.aspx` files in them as well as child folders.

In other words I wish to select ALL `.aspx` files inside that directory as well as ALL `.aspx` files in its child folders, ALL `.aspx` files in the children of those children, etc. I'm using the following PowerShell code snippet to do so:

`$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\apgdy\Downloads\test_proj -recurse -filter "*.aspx"`

When I run that in the PowerShell console and display the contents of `$files`, I get all of the files that I expect displayed in the screen buffer. However, when I try to add text to the file using the following code, I get an error:

Code:

```
$textIsAddedAfter = "<head>"
$textToAdd = "    <sometag>"

ForEach ($file in $files) {
(Get-Content $file) |
Foreach-Object {
    $_
    if($_ -match $textIsAddedAfter) {
        $textToAdd
    }
} | 
Set-Content $file
}
```

Error:

```
Get-Content : cannot find path 'C:\users\apgdy\test.aspx' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:17
+     <Get-Content <<<<  $file> |
     + CategoryInfo         : ObjectNotFound: <C:\Users\apgdy\test2.aspx:String
    > [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCo
ntentCommand
```

I get one of those for each file that it finds in `$files`
What's weird is that in the code, I told the console that the files exist in `"C:\users\apgdy\Downloads\test_proj"` and its children, not `"C:\users\apgdy"`. Why did it omit `"\Downloads\test_proj"` from the directory I told it to look for the files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Get-Content` it's not using the full file path.  Change from:

```
Get-Content $file
```

To:

```
Get-Content $file.FullName
```

Or:

```
$file | Get-Content
```

Comment: Awesome! I used .Fullname property in get-content and set-content, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!